# How to override formatting for a CCK field?

Tags: entities

I have a CCK field called "stock". I dont want visitors of the website to see the value of "stock". I want them to see either "In Stock" if the value is more than 0, or out of stock if the value is less than zero.

Any idea how I can do that without actually editing the node display template?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the type of the field you are using, there are template files for those as well e.g. a number field ([field--number-decimal.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7)). that way you would only have to override the field template, rather than the node template.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds)? You can create custom fields based upon different scenarios, etc.